# Why does not the "Warning C4172 returning address of local variable or temporary" error occur?

Tags: c, memory-management

this code, returning a local pointer variable.

But, Why does not the "Warning C4172 returning address of local variable or temporary" error occur?

The compiler does not output any errors.

```
#include<stdio.h>

static const char *test(void){
    const char *a = NULL;
    char b[64] = {0,};
    a = b;
    return a;

}

int main() {
   const char *a;
   a = test();
}
```

Comment: Apparently the compiler does not carry over the information that b is local to a. (The memory b points to could be allocated dynamically; if you return `&a` (after changing the function signature) you certainly get the warning.) Btw., gcc does not complain either.

Comment: A safety net can only stretch so far...

Comment: clang compiler seems to detect this problem: ` warning: Address of stack memory associated with local variable 'b' returned to caller`

Comment: @StoryTeller I would hope that an optimizer eliminates `a` altogether. If the optimizer can see these things, the compiler can, too, with acceptable effort, at least with an option (so that we do not degrade compile time for known good programs).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider - On the flip side, an optimizer can reduce this program to the equivalent of `return 0;` - So there may not be anything left to diagnose if it comes back to it.

Comment: @StoryTeller True enough. I chose not to include that thought (no observable behavior) in my first comment in order to focus on the essential idea ;-).

Answer (score 2):

In `C` there are two kinds of "errors" (I am using the term *error* here very loosely). Errors that **must** be caught at compile time and the compiler **is obligated** to issue a diagnostic. In this case there can be no executable created.

For instance:

```
int foo() int
{
    return 24
}
```

The above snippet of code is not a `C` program and it can't compile.

The other kind are run-time error. And while here there are a couple of them, I will focus on Undefined Behavior. Some programs on some portions of them have semantics such that **if they get executed** the behavior of the program is undefined. And, important to note here, the standard says: "no diagnostics required".

Lets take an example close to yours:

```
int* foo()
{
    int a;
    return &a;
}
```

This is technically legal. What would be illegal is to use the pointer. For instance if in any point your program does this:

```
int* x = foo();
*x = 24;
```

then your program has Undefined Behavior. And the compiler is not required to issue any diagnostics. This is so because in practice it can get very difficult, impossible or with great performance penalty to check for UB.

On the other hand if your program never uses the pointer from `foo()` then all is OK. But since the returned pointer is practically useless and most likely a bug, most compilers try to detect this case and issue a warning at compile time. It just happens that the analysis is not deep or complex enough to detect the returning of local address in your particular case.